# Android suppurt library correct usage

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an application with

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

And it uses some classes from android support library v4.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

Questions are:
1) Should i use library v7 instead of v4 ?
2) Can i use single apk for all platforms without checking `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` for importing "support" or "native" classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classes and methods in the support library you don't need to check the build version, but you need to be carefull with methods (from "native" classes) that may not be available in all versions you want to support.

As for the version of the lib you need to check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html), you only need v7 if you need somethig only available there.